# How to make posts date synchronize

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Let say i have 15 or more posts in one page. The code inside the while loop look like this

```
 <div class="post" id="<?php echo $postID?>">

    <h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>

    <div class="postmeta"> 
posted by <?php echo $author;?> , <?php echo timeAgo($postDate);?></div>
    </div>
```

this is just an a example ! So timeAgo() function convert the unix timestamp 1329569847 to human time 11 mins ago. And how to make it synchronize in real time with ajax I mean after 5 mins to change to 16 mins ago,after 4 mins to change to 20 mins ago and that to effect all posts.

---

So i managed to make it work thanks to **chenio** and **TheShellfishMeme** (beer).

And this is the code that do the magic

```
<span class="timestamp" id="5" postdate="1329576793"></span><br/>

<span class="timestamp" id="8" postdate="1329576795"></span><br/>


<script>

updateTimestamps();
setInterval(updateTimestamps, 60000);

function updateTimestamps(){
    $(".timestamp").each(function(i){

        var timestamp = $(this).attr("postdate");
var postID = $(this).attr("id");

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "myURL",
data: "postID="+ postID +'&timestamp=' + timestamp, 
cache: false,
success: function(html){

$(".timestamp#"+postID).html(html);

}
});




    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should be sorting in on the server, it should have nothing to do with JavaScript. Also you have more than one h1 on a page?

Comment: yes this is just an a example. And i do have the post unix timestamp in the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use data attributes like here http://jsfiddle.net/rXFnn/ to add the unix timestamp to a span inside the div which is meant to contain the 'time ago' string.
Then you port your timeAgo logic over to javascript and update it every minute using setInterval.

No need to do AJAX for something that simple, but note that the example below uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com).

For completeness, here is the code again:

```
<div class="postmeta"> 
    posted by Foo , <span class="timestamp" data-timestamp="1329573254200"></span> ago
</div>​

<script>
updateTimestamps();
setInterval(updateTimestamps, 60000);

function updateTimestamps(){
    $(".timestamp").each(function(i){
        var timestamp = $(this).data('timestamp');

        // Put your time ago logic here
        var timeAgo = timestamp;
        $(this).text(timeAgo);
    });
}
</script>
```

​

Comment: This answer is making use of the jquery framework. You should at least state that you are using it.

Comment: Consider writing the exact time into the span, so people without JS will get to know the time as well.

Answer (score 1):

With jquery is a good form to do it.
This is a example:

```
      <script src=jquery.js"></script>
         <script>

     <script>

    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function()
    {
// here put a url to a script to calculate time posted ago
    $('#someid').load('someurl');
    }, 60000);
    </script>
   <div class="post" id="<?php echo $postID?>">

    <h1><?php echo $title;?></h1>

    <div class="postmeta" id='someid'> 
posted by <?php echo $author;?> , <?php echo timeAgo($postDate);?></div>
    </div>
```

Other form is:

```
.....  continue
$.ajax({
 // here put a url to a script to calculate time posted ago 
  url: 'url',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#someid').html(data);

  }
}); 
......
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax and 
http://designgala.com/how-to-refresh-div-using-jquery/

i hope this can help you